# How to rollout on production while building a new Nuxt app

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

Is there any best practice for building and releasing a Vue/Nuxt project on production, especially for a large app that needs a long time to build?

Currently, if we run command

```
npm run build
```

The user is unable to access the app until the build process is done.

Is there any idea/way to make the users still able to access the site while we are still building it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More of a devops thing but the solution is simply to have 2 apps (or containers):

- 1. the current production one, totally working
- 2. the one freshly pushed and currently building

Once the build is done on the `2.`, just swap (the term used is `rollout` AFAIK) `1.` by `2.` and your users will have the new app on a fresh reload or a new visit (SPA needs to be updated).

I know that you can even make some configuration to have a progressive rollout, like

> let 20% of our userbase having the new codebase while the other 80% are on the old version, until we are sure that everything is fine and that we can rollout for everybody

Usually, JAMstack [PaaS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platform_as_a_service) (Netlify, Vercel, etc...) do that for you.